# How to put an image into an array?

Tags: matlab, components, labeling

I have [this matlab function](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/image_components/i4mat_components.m) which is supposed to label connected components in an image.
Here is the question: How can I give input to this function?

```
function [ component_num, c ] = i4mat_components ( m, n, a )
```

If you are confused, you can easily open the given link and read more information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need something along the lines of:

```
a = imread('my_epicly_awesome_picture.jpg');
```

### EDIT

To clarify, you can call your function like so:

```
a = imread('tiger.jpg');
%If your input image is RGB and you want grayscale:
%a = rgb2gray(a);
[m, n] = size(a);
[component_num, c] = i4mat_components(m, n, a);
```

Comment: ??? Input argument "m" is undefined.

Error in ==> i4mat_components at 4
  c = zeros ( m, n );

Comment: Dear friend, i don't know if you have seen the given link or not because Islam Alkan removed it(probably it was not allowed)

Comment: i tried this: i4mat_components=(411,776,'norooz.jpg');  didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Though this would be quite strange, it appears that the function requires both the image and its size as inputs.

So suppose your image is called `myimage`, then the functioncall would be:

```
[component_num,c] = i4mat_components (size(myimage,1), size(myimage,2),myimage )
```